# How can I update the VS 2010 MVC project template to include JQuery 1.5?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

Right now, when I create a new MVC project in VS2010, it automatically adds the jquery 1.4.4 files.  How would I go about updating the template so it includes the 1.5 version in place of the 1.4 version?  Is this possible?

Comment: Pro-tip: jQuery Validate 1.7 is partially incompatible with jQuery 1.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look here for starters:

http://www.thecodinghumanist.com/blog/archives/2007/5/22/how-to-edit-visual-studio-templates

Comment: I found the project template in the _Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates\CSharp\Web\1033_ folder, but that only contained one .vstemplate file. I'm wondering if the generation is handled by the MVC tool and not VS directly.

Comment: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates\CSharp\Web\1033\MvcWebApplicationProjectTemplatev2.0.cs.zip has jQuery 1.4 in it.

Comment: Thanks! I found it in the 3.0.cshtml.zip file (I'm using mvc3 projects).  I didn't realize those other zip files were there.